# Change the citation's "accessed on" date format

Tags: biblatex, citing, date, format, iso

I would like to change the date format that appears in the citation's "urldate". Right now it's at yyyy-mm-dd and I would like to change it to dd/mm/yyyy, I've tried with

```
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{//}
```

But when I enter a date with the desired format in the ref.bib file, it throws this error at me and no date is present in the pdf. And if I leave it in the old format it doesn't show properly.

```
Entry 'mantis' (ref.bib): Invalid format '07/03/2023' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring.
```

main file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.6cm, right=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=0.5cm,includefoot, footskip=30pt]{geometry}
%\usepackage[backend=biber, style=science]{biblatex} %authortitle
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{//}
\usepackage[english, czech]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, babel=other, style=iso-numeric]{biblatex} %authortitle
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareCaptionType{code}[Kód][Seznam úryvků kódu] 

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.97,0.97,0.97}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegray},
    keywordstyle=\color{codegreen},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Obr.}
\renewcommand*\listfigurename{Seznam obrázků}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Kód}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Obsah}

%\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\section{sample}

\lipsum[1] \supercite{mantis}
\newpage
\begin{center}
        \printbibliography[title={Reference}]
\end{center}
\newpage
\listoffigures 
\newpage
\end{document}
```

ref.bib file:

```
@MISC{mantis,
    title={Voron Mantis dual 5015},
    url={https://github.com/VoronDesign/VoronUsers/tree/master/printer_mods/Long/Mantis_Dual_5015},
    urldate = {2023-03-07}, 
}
```

The date format that I want to change:

[image: Default citation date format]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Can you add a small compilable example document that loads `biblatex` with the style you're using that produces the output in the image.  This way people will be able to help you more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format you see in the bibliography is controlled mainly by the style you use and additionally by the selected language. The package `datetime` has no control over `biblatex`'s date output.

`biblatex-iso690` styles like `style=iso-numeric` output most dates in ISO8601 format.

If you don't like this and prefer a more traditional output, use the option `urldate=short,`. For a Czech document like yours this gives `dd. mm. yyyy`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english, czech]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=iso-numeric,
  babel=other,
  urldate=short,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{mantis,
  title   = {Voron Mantis dual 5015},
  url     = {https://github.com/VoronDesign/VoronUsers/tree/master/printer_mods/Long/Mantis_Dual_5015},
  urldate = {2023-03-07}, 
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\section{sample}

Lorem \supercite{mantis}
\printbibliography[title={Reference}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Voron Mantis dual 5015 [online]. [B.r.]. [cit. 07.03.2023].]

---

If you want `dd/mm/yyyy`, you need `urldate=short,` and additionally also need to redefine the `short` date format for Czech.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english, czech]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=iso-numeric,
  babel=other,
  urldate=short,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{czech}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{/}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}
         {}
         {/}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{mantis,
  title   = {Voron Mantis dual 5015},
  url     = {https://github.com/VoronDesign/VoronUsers/tree/master/printer_mods/Long/Mantis_Dual_5015},
  urldate = {2023-03-07}, 
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\section{sample}

Lorem \supercite{mantis}
\printbibliography[title={Reference}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Voron Mantis dual 5015 [online]. [B.r.]. [cit. 07/03/2023].]

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I wanted.